# Get value from text box in User Control from Web Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, web-controls

I have this Web Control call uc_Register.asxc
Inside this web control got a Text Box i.e txtName

I add this Web Control into my web page call register.aspx

```
<%@ Register Src="~/controls/uc_Register.ascx" TagPrefix="ecommmbs" TagName="uc_Register" %>
<hr />
<ecommmbs:uc_SummaryCart runat="server" ID="uc_SummaryCart" />
<hr />
```

i want to get the value from txtName.txt from uc_Register.asxc at register.aspx.
how to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Register.aspx

```
TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)uc_Register.FindControl("txtName");
```

but keep in mind Page_Load() of aspx page is called first than Page_Load()of .ascx is called.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example:**

```
   Declare On User Control (PrevTransList2.ascx.cs)

    public string TransHxPage
      {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
       }

On Class file
   public interface IUserControlTransHx
    {
        string TransHxPage { get; set; }

    }
            txtSomthing.Text = TransHxPage;
```

Now On Web page SET its values

```
          PrevTransList2.TransHxPage = "POSP";
```