# How would I let 1 .aspx page use another .aspx page's code?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have 2 aspx files in my project. The first.aspx page has some content on it and when I click on a button, it will launch a frame (second.aspx that only has code to show a calendar) on the same page.

Now once that calendar(second.aspx) loads on first.aspx, I want to click a link on the calendar that will .show() a hidden DIV on the first.aspx page.

How do I access code cross pages? In other words, how can I write some code in second.aspx that will affect first.aspx.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you want to know how to pass the value selected on the calendar from the second page to the first page?

Comment: Why launch in a new frame in the first place? Why not use something like Bootstrap Modal or jQuery Dialog?

Comment: this is usually done using javascript - if I understand well... to have some answer with code, you need to provide some code....

Comment: I guess in the simplest terms, I want to click an <a> tag link that I set in the second.aspx and have it run a JS function that shows a hidden div on first.aspx.

Not sure, this is how it was set up originally.

Comment: I have all the functionality down, I just dont know how to access codes cross pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is not really possible.  You're probably approaching it the wrong way.  What you should do is turn your calendar page into a user control so that it can be used seamlessly in first.aspx.

[Here is how](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc(v=vs.85).aspx) to get started with user controls in asp.net:

After you turn it into a user control there are different approaches to getting access to the properties of the user control from your page.  [Here is one approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299812/get-value-from-text-box-in-user-control-from-web-page) using the FindControl method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm ok I see, I guess the user control would be the way to go. I will check out the guide and try to implement it into my code.

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to show and hide your div with jquery. Simple give your div a class like:

```
<div class="myCalendarDiv" style="display:none" />
```

And your Button should look like this:

```
<asp:Button id="myButton" OnClientClick="return ShowCalendar();" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowCalendar() {
    $(".myCalendarDiv").show();
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Another way would be instead of creating a seprate webpage for the calendar, as proposed you can use a jquery dialog, or make a usercontrol and embedd it on the same page.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try and go the user control way like you and above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

So since I was dealing with an Iframe, I found out that you can target the parent window which would be first.aspx.

I used "window.parent.MYFUNCTION();" to call my JavaScript function on first.aspx and show the div.